# Which Green Lantern unlocks the "Not Your Normal Green Lantern" achievement?

Tags: scribblenauts-unmasked

I'm looking at the achievements for Scribblenauts Unmasked (on Steam, if that makes a difference), and there are a series of "Not Your Normal [Hero name here]" achievements.

For all of the rest of the achievements, the first time I selected an alternate of that character it popped.  However, the Green Lantern one isn't doing so.

Is there a special/secret to unlocking this particular achievement?  Or is the game just bugged?

EDIT:

For every other character that has that achievement, when you enter, say, "Wonder Woman" into the notebook, you are greeted by a list like this:

[image: List of Scribblenauts Unmasked Wonder Womans]

And as soon as you select a character without the "(regular)" after their name, the achievement pops.

For Green Lantern, you are instead greeted by this:

[image: List of Scribblenauts Unmasked Green Lanterns]

(Note the lack of "Page 1 of n" message) And picking any of these ones doesn't seem to pop the achievement, presumably because they are not "alternate" Green Lanterns.

Comment: [There are 130](http://scribblenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Scribblenauts_Unmasked:_A_DC_Comics_Adventure#cite_ref-0) but I can't seem to find a list of all of them (I love Green Lantern).  Good luck.

Comment: It says 130 green lanterns in several places, but that may just be inclusive of all green lanterns of the lantern corps. I do not believe there are actually that many versions of Earth's eponymous GLs ("The Green Lantern") upon which I believe the achievement depends, Alan Scott/Hal Jordan/John Stewart/Guy Gardner/Kyle Rayner/Simon Baz. Which Green Lanterns you have tried?

Comment: @skovacs1 Edited in screenshots to hopefully clarify what I've tried.

Comment: Those are all standard incarnations of Green Lanterns. I don't have a copy of the game, but I do know a fair bit of DC trivia. Green Lantern has had less variation than most. I would try entering the name of a green lantern like "Hal Jordan" and see if there are any variants listed as that seems the better way to go. Alternatively try prefixing Green Lantern with a common DC variant like "Red Son" or "Blackest Night." Other variants I know, include Yellow Lantern (a variant of Hal Jordan) and Ion (a variant of Kyle Rayner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've entered the "Yellow Lantern", then the achievement popped. So my guess would be that a lantern of any other color than green should do the trick.

Comment: I don't have the game, but I also wouldn't be surprised if a non-Earth member of the Green Lantern Corp would work as well, worth a try.  But if they're being specific that it needs to be an alternate version of an established character then this specifically should work ("Yellow Lantern" is very specifically another version of Hal Jordan IIRC).  You could also try Warrior or Ion or Parallax or something like that.

Comment: you have to Spawn 150 different Green Lanterns.

Comment: @iMAGEbox You are mixing up this achievement with No Evil Shall Escape My Sight (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132770/in-scribblenauts-unmasked-how-do-you-unlock-the-no-evil-shall-escape-my-sight)

Answer (score 0):

I typed in Hal Jordan and got to choose which version of him I wanted, and then I got my achievement.