# In Scribblenauts Unmasked, how do you unlock the "No Evil Shall Escape My Sight" achievement?

Tags: achievements, scribblenauts-unmasked

I've been trying to achieve this one forever now. Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Comment: Wild guess: Become Green Lantern?

Comment: The game is advertised as having 130 different Green Lantern characters - I'm guessing you have to find them all (rather than just generating the same ones over and over) - see my related question here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132214/which-green-lantern-unlocks-the-not-your-normal-green-lantern-achievement Not an answer, since I don't have a list of said 130...

Answer (score 1):

You have to spawn 150 different Green Lanterns.

[source](http://www.exophase.com/achievement/scribblenauts-unmasked-steam/no-evil-shall-escape-my-sight/)